# how to install memcached with nginx and php-fpm

Tags: nginx, memcached, php

how to install memcached  with nginx and php-fpm

i try many time but i don't know how

with CENTOS 5.9 x86_64

my nginx folrer /etc/nignx

my php folder /webserver/php

Comment: Did you check the OS repository? In Ubuntu I could install it easily using `apt-get install`, did you try `yum install memcached` ?

Comment: after in how to config if with nginx

Comment: You don't really need to configure it with nginx, because it's a separate server, if you want it as a php session handler then that's something you need to configure on php not nginx, and make sure you have the php extension `php5-memcached`.

Comment: Umm yes you can install it:

yum install memcached and pecl install memcache and thats all.. then configure your CMS, wordpress, vbulletin etc and that will work